# Angular2 - Parse JSON into an Object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Example: I have a Entity-Class named "Person"

```
constructor(name:string,surname:string,birthdate:string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}
```

And in a "Manager"-Class I get a string that looks like a JSON:

```
{
    "name" : "testName",
    "surname" : "testSurrname",
    "birthdate" : "JJJJ:MM:DD hh:mm:ss"
}
```

So how to parse the JSON into a "Person"

```
personData : Person;
jsonData : JSON;
public toPerson(data: string): Person {
    this.jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    .?
    .?
    .?
    personData = new Person(....);
    return personData;
}
```

Comment: Where is this string coming from and why is it broken JSON? Assuming you can sort that out, the best approach is to rewrite your constructor so it looks like `constructor(data) { Object.assign(this, data); }`, then invoke it with `new Person(this.jsondata)`.

Comment: sorry, i wrote the json wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public toPerson(data: string): Person {
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

    personData = new Person(jsonData.name, jsonData.surname, jsonData.birthdate);
    return personData;
}
```

Comment: at this.jsonData.  i can only choose between this.jsonData.stringify and this.jsonData.parse...

Comment: the data is already stringified why you want to use stringify ?

Comment: could you join the chat, it would be faster :) 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137472/discussion-between-alstra-and-bougarfaoui-el-houcine

Comment: `this.`  on each of the parameters to `new Person` is unnecessary, it should just be `jsonData.*`

Comment: thnx @ssube  I forgot the `this` cuz I updated the code many times :)

Comment: This approach is not scalable to more properties.

Comment: Look my answer @torazaburo

Answer (score 2):

One more elegant solution is to use `JSON.parse` reviver:

```
public static fromJSON(json: any): Person {
    if (typeof json === 'string') {
        return JSON.parse(json, Person.reviver);
    } else if (json !== undefined && json !== null) {
        let person = Object.create(Person.prototype);
        return Object.assign(person, json);
    } else {
        return json;
    }
}

public static reviver(key: string, value: any): any {
    return key === '' ? Person.fromJSON(value) : value;
}
```